# Blog Delete Action Error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a blog style site and under each article there is the usual 'view' 'edit' and 'delete' functions for users once they are signed in. The issue is when I click on 'delete' the link it sends you to the 'view' article page and doesn't delete the article. Can't figure this one out as the delete and view paths are different in my code but do the same thing...??

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index, :show]

# GET /articles
# GET /articles.xml
# display the amount of article on the home page

def index
@articles = Article.published.page(params[:page]).per(6).ordered

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
 # format.atom #index.atom.builder
  format.xml  { render :xml => @articles }
end
end


 # GET /articles/1
 # GET /articles/1.xml
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @comment = Comment.new(:article=>@article)

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @article }
end
end

...
```

/controllers/articles_controller

```
# DELETE /articles/1.xml
 def destroy
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
 authorize! :destroy, @article
@article.destroy

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to(articles_url) }
  format.xml  { head :ok }
  end
 end
end
```

views/articles/_article.html.erb

```
<div class= "art-links">
<%= link_to 'Read', article %>
  <% if can? :update, article %>
 | <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %> |      
 <% end %>

 <% if can? :destroy, article %>
  <%= link_to 'Delete', article, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
<% end %>
  </div>
<br />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be because you don't have the right javascript files set up. Rails 3 uses unobtrusive javascript to create the `DELETE` request when you click the link. If the javascript isn't working, it will fall back to doing a `GET` which will render the `show` action.

Make sure you have `rails.js` and `prototype.js` in your layout. If you are using a javascript framework other than Prototype, you will need to have that framework (jQuery or whatever) along with the appropriate port of `rails.js`.

Comment: Good spot - I did install the "jquery-rails" gem yesterday following a Railscast episode, my understanding is that it removes the prototype.js framework. Sugar.. how do I fix this so it works again???

Comment: Did you run the `jquery:install` generator after you added the gem?

Comment: @Austin I ran the (jquery:install) cmd after running bundle install and got this crazy error - have posted shot above. Any suggestions?

Comment: Apparently you need to run `bundle update`. See the discussion here: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/41

Comment: That worked - the 'delete' btn is still not working even though everything has installed okay. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you verified that rails.js and jquery.js are being loaded on the page in question?

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
format.html { redirect_to(articles_url) }
```

should send it back to your index action, where do you want to end up?

Comment: I want it to 'delete' the article when clicked and then go back to the index page

Comment: Can you post the code for the delete link, your controller looks fine

Answer (score 0):

This case happen also in my project.

Finnaly I know the cause. It  was because my application.js that located in `app/assets/javascript` was being replaced by another `application.js` that I copy when I try to explore about bootstap.

I simply add this 3 rows back:

> //= require jquery
>
> //= require jquery_ujs
>
> //= require jquery-ui

to the `application.js` on the top row its okay.

and put this

> 

on my app/views/layout/application.html.erb

n it work..

in case if the jquery have been install n still error like me :D

sory for bad english :)

Comment: I edited a bit. Not sure what is the meaning of 'n' in your answer. Is it for 'not' or 'and'. Please use full english words.

Comment: Thank you for your advice @Jayan , n means and. Sorry, got to use n rather than and. Thanks